# change labeltext color depending on the highlighted state of button

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uilabel

I would like to change the color of text in a `label` depending on the state of a custom `button`. I tried to achieve it with in `viewdidload` as,

```
if (dialMobileNumber.highlighted == YES) 
    {
        txtMobileNumber.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 /255.0 green:160.0 /255.0 blue:224.0 /255.0 alpha:1.0];
    }
```

but it does not work. Any suggestions how can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the button to highlighted or selected? I have made the mistake many times wondering why code wasn't working but it was because I was checking the buttons highlighted state instead of selected state.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a boolean which changes every time the button is pressed, and then change the color in accordance to the boolean state.